# Does Mythic Magic Missile bypass Chthonic Steel's protection against Magic Missile?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mythic-adventures, special-materials

[*Chthonic Steel*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials/#TOC-Steel-Chthonic) says of armours made from it:

> Chthonic armor and shields negate magic missile spells that target the wearer **in a manner similar to the shield spell.**

How would this fare against [*Mythic Magic Missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Magic-Missile):

> The damage dealt by each missile increases to 2d4+1. The missiles bypass the shield spell and similar effects that block the non-mythic version of this spell.

Most of my hesitation in stating *"MMM bypasses the protection afforded by the chthonic steel"* stems from the vague nature of the text in the steel description.
**Is there a section of text that better clarifies the intent of this quality?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Chtonic Steel is of no help against a mythic magic missile.

- 1 (General case): the magic missile goes to your target and inflict damages.
- 2 (Specific case): exception to 1: if the target is protected by *magic shield*, the missile is blocked
- 3 (More specific case): exception to 2: if the missile is mythic, even if the target is protected by a shield or any similar effects the missile is not blocked

Chtonic Steel is not a more specific case of 3, it is a variation on 2. It specifically calls being similar to *magic shield* so 3 can still take precedence over it.

There is here no doubt possible in that it wouldn't block a *mythic magic missile*, no vague line that suggests it, nothing. On this point it is, as the description states, not better than a classic *magic shield*.

Comment: "The missiles bypass the shield spell *and similar effects*" ... alrighty then. I suppose that could have been read with a closer scrutiny.